# turn date separated by periods into datetime

Tags: python-3.x, loops, date, datetime, text

I have a sample list of dates that is taken from a larger sample of data. Some dates are formatted in various ways e.g. `01.11.18` vs `12.23.1983`. My goal is to convert these dates into `datetime` format

```
dates = ['01.11.18', '2.2.17', '02.02.18', '12.1.16', '12.23.1943', '12.23.19']
```

My desired output is a `datetime` format.

To do so, I have tried the following

```
from datetime import datetime
type_datetime = []
for d in dates:
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')
    type_datetime.append(datetime_object)
```

But I get an error

```
ValueError: time data '01.11.18' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

How do I change my code to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strptime follows [this formatting table](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Well, since you have multiple formats, one solution is to make a list of possible date formats and try one by one:

```
type_datetime = []
formats = ("%m.%d.%y", "%m.%d.%Y")
for d in dates:
    datetime_object = None
    for f in formats:
        try:
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(d, f)
            break
        except:
            continue
    type_datetime.append(datetime_object)
```